# Should an Accesskey attribute be unique

Tags: html, access-keys

Our CMS manufacturer delivers HTML templates that look like this:

```html
<li><a accesskey="A" href="#">Accordion</a></li>
<li><a accesskey="A" href="#">Audio/Video</a></li>
<li><a accesskey="C" href="#">Charts</a></li>
<li><a accesskey="C" href="#">Container</a></li>
<li><a accesskey="F" href="#">Forms</a></li>
```

In my opinion, the attributes have to be unique. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

It is not required. The behaviour if more than one element has the same accesskey different in different browsers:

- IE, Firefox: The next element with the pressed `accesskey` will be
  activated
- Chrome, Safari: The last element with the pressed `accesskey` will be activated
- Opera: The first element with the pressed
  `accesskey` will be activated

Comment: It appears that Firefox these days will do nothing if the accesskey is repeated. :(

Answer (score 1):

HTML provides no guidance on the subject.

A [WCAG note](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140311/F17) says offers this as a failure state for one of its tests:

> An accesskey attribute value that is not unique

In practical terms, some browsers will allow the elements to be cycled through, while others will take only one value as acceptable.

---

TLDR: There's no requirement that they be unique, but duplicates will cause issues.